# When I deploy my React file to netlify, why do i get a 404 of page not found?

Tags: reactjs, netlify

My deployed React site works fine i.e everything works except when I click on pagination buttons it returns a 404 of not found but it works fine locally? is it because I'm using an 'a' tag>

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening because you need to create a `_redirects` file. See [this Netlify post](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/01/16/redirect-rules-for-all-how-to-configure-redirects-for-your-static-site/) explaining it, specifically this section:

> Another common use case for having redirects with an explicit status code in Netlify is in enabling history pushstate for clean URLs in single page applications (SPAs). In a setup without redirects, a url like, outrageous-penguin.netlify.com/about is routed to a 404: Not Found error page on page refresh. In a SPA, routes are client side rendered, meaning that route changes only correspond to changes in page content. Without an explicit redirect, the Netlify bots assume you’re requesting a page separate from /index.html and since that page doesn’t actually exist, it returns an error. To enable clean URLs in your Netlify deployed SPAs, add the following rule to your redirects file.
>
> `/* /index.html 200`

Answer (score 0):

I Changed the 'a' tag to button and it works.